# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function result_array() on bool

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using CodeIgniter on a hosting, and I want to get some data from a table in SQL Server database in other cloud server.

```
public function do_login() {
        $u      = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('u'));
        $ta     = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('ta'));
        $p      = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('p'));
            
        $this->db->where('username', $u);
        $this->db->where('password', $p);
        $q_cek  = $this->db->get('T_ADMIN');
        // $q_cek   = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM t_admin WHERE username = '".$u."' AND password = '".$p."'");
        //$j_cek    = $q_cek->num_rows();
        $j_cek= count($q_cek->num_rows());
        $d_cek  = $q_cek->row();
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
        
        if($j_cek == 1) {
            $data = array(
                    'admin_id' => $d_cek->id,
                    'admin_user' => $d_cek->username,
                    'admin_nama' => $d_cek->nama,
                    'admin_ta' => $ta,
                    'admin_level' => $d_cek->level,
            'admin_valid' => true
                    );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('index.php/admin');
        } else {    
        $this->session->set_flashdata("k", "<div id=\"alert\" class=\"alert alert-error\">username or password is not valid</div>");
    redirect('index.php/admin/login');
    }
}
```

But I have message

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function num_rows() on bool

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Have you started by reading the documentation yet? e.g.: [Handling Errors](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#handling-errors)

Comment: Aside... please tell us you aren't storing plaintext passwords in your database. If you must handle passwords in your application please read up on "salting-and-hashing of passwords."

Comment: username : ADMIN and password : admin

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this block of code is that you will get an error on

```
$j_cek= count($q_cek->num_rows());
```

count is on an array or object, ->num_rows() provides an int.

Comment: The issue is that `$this->db->get('T_ADMIN')` returned false due to some kind of error. OP isn't checking that their pyodbc calls are successful, nor reporting errors.